# What will happen when getSimCountryIso() is called on Android Tablets?

Tags: java, android, tablet, country-codes

In my Android app, in order to determine certain features, I'm checking a device's ISO country code using `getSimCountryIso()` and `getNetworkCountryIso()`.
Tested this on my real mobile devices and emulators and all returned certain values without any errors.

One of them is my daily driver phone which has a SIM card in it, but the others have no SIM cards. So at first, I thought both `getSimCountryIso()` and `getNetworkCountryIso()` always return some values, but now I'm in doubt because all my real devices used to have SIM cards once and emulators may differ from real ones.

I wonder what will happen when those are called on real Tablets which **NEVER HAD SIM cards** in them and have only WiFi connections. Can I always expect a certain value? Or an exception or null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought you would get a NullPointerException, but having tested it on a tablet - Pixel C, running Nougat - I actually got back empty Strings for both `TelephonyManager.getSimCountryIso()` and `TelephonyManager.getNetworkCountryIso()`.

I had assumed the result would be an NPE because calling `PackageManager.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_TELEPHONY)` on a tablet will return `false`. That was enough to tell me that you shouldn't be trying to get SIM or network country codes this way on a non-phone device. However, if you try to retrieve the `TelephonyManager` using `Context.getSystemService()` on such a device anyway, you still get a non-null `TelephonyManager` - it just won't be helpful in providing a sim or network country.

In my opinion, if you are dealing with a device that does not have the Telephony system feature, you ought to consider using GPS location, or the user-set locale if you really don't want to encroach on location permissions and can tolerate the user-set locale not being where the user necessarily is.

Comment: Thank you so much for your test and kind answer! It helped a lot, I would never know without this..

Comment: FYI, I tested on Genymotion's Pixel C Nougat emulator. PackageManager.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_TELEPHONY) returned true, and both TelephonyManager.getSimCountryIso() and TelephonyManager.getNetworkCountryIso() returned the string "us". Again, your answer is really helpful, thanks!

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help. I wonder if your Pixel C returned true and "us" because of some setting in the emulator... Strange...